# Update xml node value from secondary table using join based current node value

Tags: sql-server, xml, join, xml.modify

Table **dbo.table_a** contains a XML column **foo**. Every row has a XML-tree in the a XML-column. 
Secondary table **dbo.table_b** contains old value **old_val** and new value **new_val**

The XML-tree looks like this

```
<root>
  <Customer>
    <Name>ACME</Name>
  </Customer>
  <Def>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <CIds>
      <Id>ABC</Id>
      <Id>DEF</Id>
    </CIds>
  </Def>
</root>
```

Please Note that /root/Def/CIds can contain zero or several child nodes called Id.

**dbo.table_b** looks like this

```
+---------+---------+
| old_val | new_val |
+---------+---------+
| ABC     |     123 |
| DEF     |     456 |
+---------+---------+
```

I need to replace the value for every *Id* by joining the current xml node value with **dbo.table_b** on **old_val** and replacing the xml node value with new_val.
ABC should be replace with 123 and DEF with 456

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to achieve this, due to the fact that even now, in 2018, the `replace value of` XML method still does not support modification of multiple nodes.

The simplest approach is the insert+delete tactic, as in the following example:

```
declare @TableA table (
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    XData xml not null
);

declare @TableB table (
    OldValue varchar(50),
    NewValue int
);

insert into @TableA (XData)
select N'<root>
  <Customer>
    <Name>ACME</Name>
  </Customer>
  <Def>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <CIds>
      <Id>ABC</Id>
      <Id>DEF</Id>
    </CIds>
  </Def>
</root>';

insert into @TableB (OldValue, NewValue)
values
    ('ABC', 123),
    ('DEF', 456);

-- Before
select * from @TableA;

update a set XData.modify('insert sql:column("sq.NewData") after /root[1]/Def[1]/CIds[1]')
from @TableA a
    cross apply (
        select b.NewValue as [Id]
        from @TableB b
        where a.XData.exist('/root/Def/CIds/Id[text() = sql:column("b.OldValue")]') = 1
        for xml path(''), type, root('CIds')
    ) sq(NewData);

update a set XData.modify('delete /root[1]/Def[1]/CIds[1]')
from @TableA a;

-- After
select * from @TableA;
```

Its weakness is that it reconstructs the entire `/CIds` node, so if you have any additional data in it, like attributes, it might be too cumbersome to recreate. In this case you might have better success with a FLWOR update, but they tend to be quite slow, compared to other options.

Alternatively, you might run a series of atomic updates in a loop. As unpleasant as it may sound, it will actually work, especially if your actual XML is much more complex than the provided example.

Comment: I haven't hade the time yet but the /CIds structure always contains Id (it not empty), no other child elements or attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with looping and updating. Although @Roger Wolf's code snippet worked I couldn't make it work in my environment.

```
declare @I int
declare @old varchar(50)
declare @new varchar(50)

select @I = max([foo].value('count(/root/Def/CustomerIds/CIds)', 'int'))
FROM dbo.table_a where [foo].exist('(count(/root/Def/CustomerIds/CIds/Id)') = 1

while @I > 0 
begin

select @old = [foo].value('(/count(/root/Def/CustomerIds/CIds/Id)[sql:variable("@I")][1]', 'varchar(50)') 
from dbo.table_a
where [foo].exist('(/count(/root/Def/CustomerIds/CIds/Id)[sql:variable("@I")]') = 1

set @new = dbo.ConvertOldNew(@old)


  update dbo.table_a
  set [foo].modify
    ('replace value of ((/count(/root/Def/CustomerIds/CIds/Id)[sql:variable("@I")]/text())[1]
      with (sql:variable("@new"))')
  where [foo].exist('(/count(/root/Def/CustomerIds/CIds/Id)[sql:variable("@I")]') = 1
  set @I = @I - 1
end
```

Please note that `dbo.ConvertOldNew` is a function returning the new value based on the old value.